# Trigger to check for the availability of department number in the department table, before inserting or updating a record in the employee table

Tags: database, oracle, database-trigger

I created a trigger as follows:

```
create or replace trigger t4
before insert or update on employee1
for each row
declare
cursor c1 is select depno from department where
depno=:new.depno;
c2 c1%rowtype;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into c2;
  if(c1%found) then 
    raise_application_error(-20008,'No such department');
  end if;
  close c1;
end;
```

It was created successfully.. This is how my employee1 relation looks like:

```
EMPNO   EMPNAME     DESIGNATION     DATEOFJOIN  SALARY  DEPNO   GRADE
101     Sharon      Manager         01-JAN-00   10000   1        D
102     Gayathri    Manager         01-JAN-00   10000   1        D
103     Sharmi      HR              02-FEB-00   9900    3        D
111     Raj         Salesman        05-JAN-00   5000    1        D
```

This is how my department relation looks like:

```
DEPNO   DEPNAME     DEPLOCATION
1       Marketing   block a
3       Production  block c
```

I tried to insert a row into the employee1 relation to check whether my trigger works..

```
Insert into employee1 values(110,'Shan','Manager','01-JAN-00',10000,2,'D');
```

But the following error shows up:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C004025) violated - parent key not found
```

**But I want the error that I've raised in the trigger to be displayed**
I know this is a bad idea to do something like this. But I have to do this for my assignment.. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: post the definition of the table employee1 since i suspect there is a foreign key reference

Comment: Yeah, I have a foreign key reference.. Won't the trigger work if so??

Comment: you have to insert the primary key in the parent table first before inserting into the table where the foreign key in referenced

Comment: Yeah I know that... But that's what my question is about...  So inorder to make my trigger work, I should not make use of the primary key and foreign key, right??

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
if(c1%NOTfound)
      ---
      ???
```